# error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘QVector<int>’ and ‘QCharRef’)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm trying to analyze a file in `qt5`.

File is vector that have for each position a row of a file and counter is a vector where i store the results of the analysis

> error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘QVector’ and ‘QCharRef’)

```
void FileAnalyzer(QVector<QString> &file,QVector<int> &counter)
{
    counter.resize(260);
    for(int row=0,lenFile=file.size();row<lenFile;row++)
    {
        for(int car=0;file[row][car]!='\0';car++)
        {
            if(file[row][car]==' ')contatore[256]++;//space
            counter[file[row][car]]++;//<-- here i get the error
            counter[259]++;
        }
        counter[257]++;//row
    }
    counter[257]++;//last row
    counter[258]=counter[256]+counter[257];//words number
}
```

Comment: @orenzo De Luca The error message is enough clear.

Comment: What is your question? The type of the counter index (`int`) and the file content (`QCharRef`) don't match, which is what the compiler is already telling you. Are you looking for a way to convert the file contents to a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to use `QCharRef` as an index. You should use `QChar` instead:

```
counter[file[row].at(car).unicode()]++
```